# Ubuntu Focal headless setup on Raspberry pi 4 - cloud init wifi initialisation before first reboot

Tags: ubuntu-server, raspberry-pi4, cloud-init

i'm having trouble in setting up a full headless install for Ubuntu Server Focal (ARM) on a Raspberry pi 4 using cloud init config. The whole purpose of doing this is to simplify the SD card swap in case of failure. I'm trying to use cloud-init config files to apply static config for lan/wlan, create new user, add ssh authorized keys for the new user, install docker etc. However, whatever i do it seems the Wifi settings are not applied before the first reboot.

Step1: burn the image on SD Card.
Step2: rewrite SD card system-boot/network_config and system-boot/user-data with config files

> network-config

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: false
    optional: true
    addresses: [192.168.100.8/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.100.2
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.100.2, 8.8.8.8]
wifis:
  wlan0:
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "AP-NAME":
        password: "AP-Password"
    dhcp4: false
    addresses: [192.168.100.13/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.100.2
    nameservers:
      #search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
      addresses: [192.168.100.2, 8.8.8.8]
```

> user-data

```
chpasswd:
  expire: true
  list:
    - ubuntu:ubuntu

# Enable password authentication with the SSH daemon
ssh_pwauth: true
groups:
  - myuser
  - docker
users:
  - default
  - name: myuser
    gecos: My Name
    primary_group: myuser
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAA....
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: $6$rounds=4096$7uRxBCbz9$SPdYdqd...

packages:
  - apt-transport-https
  - ca-certificates
  - curl
  - gnupg-agent
  - software-properties-common
  - git
runcmd:
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=arm64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
  - systemctl start docker
  - systemctl enable docker
## TODO: add git deployment and configure folders
power_state:
  mode: reboot
```

During the first boot cloud-init always applies the fallback network config.

I also tried to apply the headless config for wifi as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md).

> Created wpa_supplicant.conf and copied it to SD system-boot folder.

```
trl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=RO

network={
    ssid="AP-NAME"
    psk="AP-Password"
}
```

> Also created an empty ssh file and copied it to system-boot

The run commands always fail since during the first boot cloud-init applies the fallback network config. After reboot, lan/wlan settings are applied, the user is created, ssh authorized keys added. However i still need to ssh into the PI and install install the remaining packages: docker etc, and i wanted to avoid this. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this?

Comment: Im also having issues with this.

Its specific to using Wifi as only network connection. Everything works with Ethernet port as primary

Comment: @Christopher nope, i will test to see if chd recommendation for using the ethernet port as primary works.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you ever found a workaround, but I'll share some information I found when researching options.

- Ubuntu's [Raspberry Pi WiFi Setup Page](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#3-wifi-or-ethernet) states the need for a reboot when using `network-config` with WiFi:

> Note: During the first boot, your Raspberry Pi will try to connect to this network. It will fail the first time around. Simply reboot `sudo reboot` and it will work.

There's an interesting workaround & approach in [this repo](https://gitlab.com/Bjorn_Samuelsson/raspberry-pi-cloud-init-wifi).

- It states it was created for 18.04, but it should work with 20.04 as both Server versions use `netplan` and `systemd-networkd`.

Personally, I've gone a different route.

- I create custom images that contain my settings & packages, then burn to uSD or share via a TFTP server. I was surprised at how easy this was.

  - There's a good post on creating custom images [here](https://opensource.com/article/20/5/disk-image-raspberry-pi)
  - Some important additional info is [here](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi/qemu-user-static#chroot_in_to_the_image)